# Apply lambda function on multiple columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Let's suppose that I have this `DataFrame` in `pandas`:

```
    year    text_1                 text_2
0   1999    ['Sunny', 'weather']   ['Foggy', 'weather']
1   2005    ['Rainy, 'weather']    ['Cloudy', 'weather']
```

and I want to tranform it to this:

```
    year    text_1           text_2
0   1999    'Sunny weather'  'Foggy weather'
1   2005    'Rainy weather'  'Cloudy weather'
```

For this reason I do this:

```
df[['text_1', 'text_2']] = df[['text_1', 'text_2']].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x), axis=1)
```

but then I get the following error:

```
TypeError: ('sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found', 'occurred at index 0')
```

Also, I do this:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x['text_1'], x['text_2'],), axis=1)
```

but then I get the following error:

```
TypeError: ('join() takes exactly one argument (2 given)', 'occurred at index 0')
```

How can I apply this function on multiple columns (in one line)?

I am saying in one line because I could apply the function separately at each column or define a function and call it to make it work.

However, I am looking for the most concise solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) if need processing each value element wise:

```
df[['text_1', 'text_2']] = df[['text_1', 'text_2']].applymap(' '.join)
print (df)
   year         text_1          text_2
0  1999  Sunny weather   Foggy weather
1  2005  Rainy weather  Cloudy weather
```

Or combine [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with [`Series.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
df[['text_1', 'text_2']] = df[['text_1', 'text_2']].apply(lambda x: x.str.join(' '))
```

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps I was not very clear. I do not want to concatenate the strings from the two columns. I want the apply the function at the two columns separately.

Comment: @PoeteMaudit - Is possible create some sample data? Be free change `df = pd.DataFrame({'text_1':[['a','b'], ['ss', 'dd']],
                   'text_2':[['k','t'], ['df', 'da']]})

print (df)`

Comment: By the way, your second solution looks very similar to the ones which I tried above but they did not work. But it looks like .join() differs quite a bit from str.join() .

Comment: @PoeteMaudit - yes, because there is used pandas function `str.join`, not python function `.join`

Comment: Yes, I know. I am just mentioning that they differ quite a bit :)

Answer (score 1):

sample data

```
             A             B
0  [asdf, asf]  [eeee, tttt]
```

---

```
df['combined'] = df.apply(lambda x: [' '.join(i) for i in list(x[['A','B']])], axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
             A             B               combined
0  [asdf, asf]  [eeee, tttt]  [asdf asf, eeee tttt]
```

---

Update

```
df[['A','B']] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series([' '.join(x['A']),' '.join(x['B'])]), axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
          A          B
0  asdf asf  eeee tttt
```